# Don't force round in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rounding

I have a problem in my stored procedure.

In C# I have the following variable:

```
decimal ART12 = 10547,42;
```

and in the stored procedure, I have this code:

```
@ART12 DECIMAL(18,2) = 0;

INSERT INTO #tmp (articolo, totale)
VALUES('12',@ART12)
```

The table `#tmp` has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
  articolo varchar(10) null
  ,finoa varchar(50) null
  ,parametro varchar(30) null
  ,quantita decimal(18,2) null
  ,totale decimal(18,2) null
  ,annoesercizio int null
  ,idcompagnia int null
  ,idagenzia int null
  ,idagente int null
  ,progressivogestione int null
)
```

When I send the value of the variable ART12 to the stored procedure, this is rounded **automatically**. If the value is 10547,42 the code return 10547,00. But I need of 10547,42!

Any solution? 
Thank you very much.

-- UPDATE --
This is the code of the funcion in C#

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(m_connString);
sqlConn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_GetElencoArt00_Riepilogo";

SqlParameter spPars32 = new SqlParameter();
spPars32.ParameterName = "@ART12";
spPars32.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
spPars32.Value = ART12;
cmd.Parameters.Add(spPars32);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        sqlConn.Close();
        sqlConn.Dispose();
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(sqlConn);
        sqlConn = null;

        return ds;
```

Comment: How are you passing the value of the variable to the stored procedure?

Comment: Something, somewhere, isn't respecting the number of decimal places, but it's not in the pieces of code you've shown us so far. So we'll need to see the code that passes the parameter through ADO and any changes to `@ART12` in the stored proc.

Comment: Have you tried using `10547.42` instead of `10457,42`? What is the data type of the parameter?

Comment: what's with the commas?

Comment: @TMcKeown it's european, they use commas instead of decimal

Comment: Quite a lot of the world uses comma for a decimal point, and full stops for a thousands separator. Does @Aaron's suggestion work?

Comment: I already debugged the C# code, the value is passed correctly.

Comment: You specified `SqlDbType.Decimal` - but you **didn't** specify a `Scale` - by default, you get `Scale = 0` (number of digits after decimal point)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I send to the store other 10 values whit comma and all work. I already have other stored procedure whit similar parameters/passed values and all work.

Comment: @marc_s the code was assigned to me, unfortunately. I have not decided the names

Comment: @marc_s I will try to set the `Scale`

Comment: @BlackICE - I wouldn't describe the *alternative* to using commas "decimal" - they use a "decimal comma", you use a "decimal point" - they're both "decimals".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't know the terminology, thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `SqlParameter` as below , Set the **Precision**  and the **Scale**

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ART12", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Precision = 18;
parameter.Scale = 2;
parameter.Value = 10547.42m; // or set value from ART12 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Should I need to set the `Precision` and `Scale` properties prior to assigning the value to the parameter? or Is there any order I need to honor?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `.` instead of `,` as decimal separator.

You additionally need an m at the end of the value to convert the floating point value from double to the shorter type decimal.

```
decimal ART12 = 10547.42m;
```

Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Comment: I have ALL the program whit `,` for decimal separator and all works correctly.